# How to iterate trough VueJS components and change attribute values

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to build a visualisation for sorting algorithms, using VueJS. I managed to get everything working at the moment with bubble sort as an example. I just want to change the colors of the elements that are compared when the sorting happens. My Bar element has a color porp and i want to change that inside my bubbleSort function loop so that whenever an element is compared to another element one becomes blue and one green, after the comparison ends the next elements become blue and green and so forth.

The question is: How can I iterate trough my Bar elements and change the color attribute?

I have tried getAttribute() as in vanilla JS but its not working with VueJS, i have tried using the $attr but it says its undefined.

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="menu-bar">
      <button v-on:click="bubbleSort">Sort</button>
      <button v-on:click="arrayPopulate">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <Bar v-for="elem in array" v-bind:key="elem" :color="color" :value="elem" class="elem" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as HF from "../algorithms/helperfunctions";
import Bar from "./Bar.vue";

export default {
  name: "Element",
  components: {
    Bar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      array: [],
      color: "red",
      current: "blue",
      comparing: "green"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    arrayPopulate() {
      this.array = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 10);
        if (!this.array.includes(n)) {
          this.array.push(n);
        }
      }
    },
    async bubbleSort() {
      //let elements = document.getElementsByTagName("Bar");
      let len = this.array.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
          if (this.array[j] > this.array[j + 1]) {
            HF.arraySwap(this.array, j + 1, j);
            await HF.sleep();
          }
        }
      }
      return this.array;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.arrayPopulate();
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried `$attrs` or `this.$attrs` in the child component instead of `$attr`, btw seems you are passing `:color="color"` it in the correct way to the child

Comment: Specifically to access the colour attribute in the child: `$attrs.color` or `this.$attrs.color`

Answer (score 0):

Appropriate way to set properties in Vue is to provide them from child to parent, without interfering with setAttribu
The most straightforward approach would be to dynamically get color based on elem.
Something like this will do:

```html
<Bar v-for="elem in array" v-bind:key="elem" :color="getColor(elem)" :value="elem" class="elem" />

methods: {
  getColor(elem) {
    return elem > 0.5 ? 'red' : 'green';
  }
}
```

However in production ready application **I'd provide color property alongside with element**, because method is called on every render and it is not best for performance.

```js
    arrayPopulate() {
      this.array = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 10);
        if (!this.array.includes(n)) {
          this.array.push({n, color: n > 0.5 ? 'red' : 'green'});
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Your way just makes them green and if I try and use the reset button it gives me a key error of key undefined and after i modify the sort function it only sorts one element of the array, but the object idea is good as i managed to change the color how i wanted.

Comment: Of course, I don't know the exact logic that you intend to use, so it is just an example :) 
Try to use `:key="elem.n"` to make sure that your key is unique